# ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'locations' in Exe. Python

Tags: python, executable

I created successfully an .exe file for my python code. As a .py file, it works like a charm. But when I try to run it from the exe version, I get error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CreateAS.pyw", line 14, in <module>
  File "pulp\__init__.pyc", line 33, in <module>
  File "pulp\pulp.pyc", line 103, in <module>
  File "pulp\solvers.pyc", line 101, in <module>
  File "pulp\solvers.pyc", line 59, in initialize
  File "ConfigParser.pyc", line 532, in get
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'locations'
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Related Part of My code:

[image]

And my Config file:

[Download the Config](http://www.sendspace.com/file/im7mht)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution. There is a solvers.py in Pulp directory. Inside it, I replaced the DIRNAME to the fullpath of the Pulp directory as follows:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    DIRNAME = r"C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PuLP-1.4.7-py2.6.egg\pulp"
    config_filename = os.path.join(DIRNAME,
                                   PULPCFGFILE) else: #run as a script
    from pulp import __file__ as fname
    DIRNAME = r"C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PuLP-1.4.7-py2.6.egg\pulp"
    config_filename = os.path.join(DIRNAME,
                                   PULPCFGFILE) cplex_dll_path, coinMP_path, gurobi_path, cbc_path, glpk_path = \
        initialize(config_filename)
```

But for distribution purposes, You dont need to do the thing above. You should include pulp folder to the project. And add the code below to the top of your project:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PuLP-1.4.7-py2.6.egg\pulp")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the section exists. If it does not - add it

```
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
if not config.has_section("locations"):
    config.add_section("locations")
```

Comment: I added your code into the main frame. But the problem continues.

Comment: I also added it to the top of the code immediately after import ConfigParser command and before import pulp command.

Comment: Do try to post your sources and your config fle